# Error in removing outliers and fitting curve to GPS data with python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, smoothing

I'm trying to remove outliers from a series of GPS Points, fit a curve through them and carry out smoothing if needed. For this, I'm using a B-spline interpolation function (Through Scipy functions Splprep and Splev). However, I get an exact plot that passes through all the points and does not remove any outliers. How do I remove these outliers and fit the curve?

Since the original GPS log file had too many points to be displayed clearly on the plot, I first reduced the number of points using Ramer-Douglas-Peucker line simplification algorithm. And since, a plot can sometimes be a closed path like this GPX file, and a function cannot be written directly to express it, I considered the spline as the method of choice to fit these data points smoothly. However, changing the parameter 's' (Smoothing condition attribute in Splprep) leads to the fitted line disappearing completely. Also, to compute the error between the original plot and the fitted plot, do we have to use the Mean Square Error function?

```
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import gpxpy
from rdp import rdp

with open('my_run_001.gpx') as fh:
    gpx_file = gpxpy.parse(fh)
    segment = gpx_file.tracks[0].segments[0]
    coords = pd.DataFrame([
    {'lat': p.latitude,
     'lon': p.longitude,
     'ele': p.elevation,
     'time': p.time} for p in segment.points])
coords.head(3)
plt.plot(coords.lon[::18], coords.lat[::18],'ro')
plt.show()

simple_coords = rdp(coords[['lon', 'lat']].values, epsilon=1e-4)
print("{} points reduced to {}!".format(coords.shape[0], simple_coords.shape[0]))
plt.plot(simple_coords[:, 0], simple_coords[:, 1], 'ro')
plt.show()

dat = np.array([(x,y) for x,y in zip(simple_coords[:, 0], simple_coords[:, 1])])
#dat = np.array([(x,y) for x,y in zip(coords.lon[::18], coords.lat[::18])])
tck, u = splprep(dat.T, u=None, s=0.0, per=1, t=10)
u_new = np.linspace(u.min(), u.max(), 1000)
x_new, y_new = splev(u_new, tck, der=0)

plt.plot(dat[:,0], dat[:,1],'ro')
plt.plot(x_new, y_new, 'b--')
plt.show()
```

Currently, I get a plot that looks as shown below (Outliers to be removed are circled in yellow):
[image: Spline Plot]
Reference for GPX Data: https://github.com/stevenvandorpe/testdata/blob/master/gps_coordinates/gpx/my_run_001.gpx

Comment: your plot looks good, what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is how can I remove outliers in the GPS data and still keep a smooth curve fit?

Comment: your curve is already rather smooth. but if you want to remove more, you need to define the criteria, which point you'd rather remove, and run RANSAC or something similar.

Comment: I thought RANSAC is for linear regression models? Since this plot is not linear, can it still be used?

Comment: Would it be possible to compute the average distance between points as a possible way to remove outliers before applying the spline?

Comment: RANSAC can take any metrics you provide, sample the points, remove the outliers. Still, I don't see many outliers on your chart, which are the ones you don't like?

Comment: I have updated the chart to also show the outliers that I want removed

Comment: Would this be a possible implementation technique? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325067/sklearn-ransac-linear-regression-results-vary-wildly